# Getting BlInitializeLibrary Failed 0x0000017 error while booting WinPE through bootmgfw.efi

Tags: windows-10, memory, uefi, bootloader, winpe

I am trying to load a WinPE file from bootmgfw.efi after downloading bootmgfw.efi via TFTP.
But once downloaded, I am getting a

> BlInitializeLibrary Failed error

Why is that? And what could be the solution?